# In a Rails Controller, how can i differentiate between a parameter not being present and a parameter being sent as null?

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, controller

I'm working on a Rails API, and I'd like to differentiate on the requests received by my controller between the cases where a parameter is not present (so the default value that I have defined will take place), and when the parameter is explicitly sent as null, so that in this case the null value will have a different behavior from the default.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can detect whether the key is present in the params hash, and whether a nil value is assigned. But this is not a good idea. It would be better to use the value 'default' as the trigger for inserting the default value, and some other value (e.g. the string "null") to indicate a nil value.

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you can differentiate:

1. `params.key?(:key_name)` will tell whether the `key_name` is present in the params or not.
2. You can check for `params[:key_name]` to validate whether the value is `nil` or not if `params.key?(:key_name)` is `true`.